# How to add row value from previous date?

Tags: mysql

```
Barcode Incoming Outgoing Stock Date
1       10       5        5     2015-1-3
2       3        2        1     2015-1-3
1       2        1        1     2015-1-4
```

My current Query's output is shown above. What i need is to add the stock from the previous date of the same barcode to the latest. As Shown below

```
Barcode Incoming Outgoing Stock Date
1       10       5        5     2015-1-3
2       3        2        1     2015-1-3
1       2        1        6     2015-1-4
```

Is there a way to make this possible? my current query is nested but looks like this. not working though

```
Select
    Barcode,
    incoming,
    outgoing,
    (incoming - outgoing + Stock_prev_value) as Stock,
    currentDate
from (select ....
)as myquery
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

currentDate => DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)

instead of requesting you can also trigger/add a table 'stock_history' per day :

-barcode

-stock

-date

Comment: How would i execute this?, make sum of stock when day is less than current date?

Comment: SELECT SUM(stock), Barcode FROM `your_table` WHERE date < CURDATE() GROUP BY Barcode

=> according you have only one couple barcode/date per row